# Erro em reverso na linguagem C

Tags: c, ponteiro

Boa tarde

Gostaria de entender porque está dando erro neste código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    char alfabeto[] = "abcdefghij";
    muda_letraa(alfabeto);
    printf("%s\n",alfabeto);
}

void muda_letraa(char *alfa)
{
    char *inicio = alfa;
    char *final;
    
    printf("alfa (%p)\n", alfa);
    while(*alfa)
    {
        printf("%c\n",*alfa);
        alfa++;
    }
    printf("alfa (%p)\n", alfa);
    
    printf("final (%p)\n", final);
    final = final + (alfa - inicio);
    printf("final (%p)\n", final);
    
    printf("alfa (%p)\n", alfa);
    alfa = inicio;
    printf("alfa (%p)\n", alfa);
    
    final++;
    *final = NULL;
    final--;
    
    int i;
    while(*alfa)
    {
        printf("alfa => E: %p , V: %c      ============       final => E: %p , V: %c\n", alfa, *alfa, final, *final);
        *final = *alfa;
        printf("alfa => E: %p , V: %c      ============       final => E: %p , V: %c\n", alfa, *alfa, final, *final);
        final--;
        alfa++;
    }
}
```

Eu percebi que é no **final--** que ele está dando erro.

Agradeço desde já.

Obrigado

Comment: Um dos erros é que você esta adicionando um ```NULL``` a uma string a maneira correta de adicionar nulo a strings é ```'\0'``` ou seja ```*final = NULL;``` deve ficar assim ```*final = '\0';```.

Comment: E se por acaso na execução desse codigo surgir algum erro do tipo ```warning: implicit declaration of function ‘muda_letraa’``` umas das maneiras de solucionar isso é declarando a função ```main(void)``` depois da função ````muda_letraa(char *alfa)````

Comment: @ZéReisM.Olliver obrigado pela dia do '\0'. Eu troquei, mas ainda está dando o erro. Ao executar o programa, o depurador do Windows dá uma mensagem que o programa parou de funcionar.

Comment: o que pretende fazer com esse programa? o que faz com `muda_letraa()` por exemplo?  Na primeira vez que mostra `final` ainda não foi inicializado. Habilitou os avisos do compilador?

Comment: Bom dia. Então @arfneto, o programa é para reverter os caracteres do alfabeto, mas usando o ponteiro. Sobre os avisos do compilador, sim ele emite apenas esse: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘muda_letraa’.

Comment: engraçado é que se eu tiro o **final--**, o código roda. Mas ele não passa pelos endereço da memória.

Comment: O código está errado. Apenas não cancela porque `final` pode não ter sentido

Answer (score 0):

Está errado do modo como escreveu.

Imagino que pretendia usar `i` para salvar o valor. Mas não fez isso. Sequer usou a variável. E também usou `final` sem ter qualquer valor.

Habilite sempre os avisos do compilador...

Vou te mostrar uma maneira comum de fazer isso

#### saída do exemplo

```
==> Antes:      abcdefghij


        End. Inicio: 0x007CFE50
        End. final:  0x007CFE5A
        Tamanho: 10

        primeira letra: 'a'
        ultima letra: 'j'

==> Depois:     jihgfedcba
```

#### O código

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inverte(char* alfa);

void main(void)
{
    char alfabeto[] = "abcdefghij";
    printf("==> Antes:\t%s\n\n", alfabeto);
    inverte(&alfabeto[0]);
    printf("==> Depois:\t%s\n\n", alfabeto);
}

void inverte(char* alfa)
{
    char* inicio = alfa;
    char* final  = alfa;

    while (*final != 0) final++; // encontra o fim
    const int tamanho = final - inicio;
    printf(
        "\n\tEnd. Inicio: 0x%p"
        "\n\tEnd. final:  0x%p"
        "\n\tTamanho: %d\n\n",
        inicio, final, tamanho);

    final--; // aponta para a ultima letra
    printf("\tprimeira letra: '%c'\n\tultima letra: '%c'\n\n", *inicio, *final);

    for (int ix = 0; ix < tamanho/2; ix += 1)
    {   // inverte as pontas
        char temp = *(inicio + ix);        
        *(inicio + ix) = *(final - ix);
        *(final - ix) = temp;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compare com seu programa e acho que vai entender. A lógica comum é considerar que vai tratar das pontas para o centro trocando os caras de lugar. Se não conseguir ver isso no exemplo escreva de volta...

Comment: boa tarde. Então referente ao i, eu esqueci de apagar, pois era de um for que eu tentei fazer no lugar do while (tipo: for(i=0;final[i] != NULL;i++) ). Quanto ao final, eu declarei a variável no início e depois atribui um valor dentro dela ( final = final + (alfa - inicio); ). Eu entendi o seu código. Eu só queria entender o porque do meu ter falhado. Aonde está o erro, pois comentando o final-- que está dentro do while, o programa não dá erro, mas também não fazer a reversão dos caracteres. O ponto aqui é entender de fato, o que esta errado?

Comment: voce sequer esta copiando os dados de um lado para o outro.  Está errado. Onde está a cópia de uma letra sequer? E o `final` não inicializado? Tem que ter um lugar intermediario para poder inverter os valores. Escreva como eu mostrei. O fato de um programa compilar não é relevante. Apenas indica que tem chance de gerar um código.

Comment: `final = final + (alfa - inicio);` você entende que escreveu isso depois do `printf()` onde mostra esse valor? Que pretende com a linha `alfa = inicio` ?   `alfa` é local.

Comment: inverter uma string não muda o tamanho. Porque escreve `*final - NULL`? E porque usou `NULL` e não `0`?

Comment: Tá, vamos lá. Vou tentar explicar a minha lógica. Eu criei duas variáveis do tipo ponteiro, onde uma recebe o endereço de início da variável que tem as caracteres (inicio recebe alfa) e a outra que vai receber a quantidade total de caracteres para posicionar a variável no endereço final para depois ir decrementando o endereço (final).

Comment: Então: inicio = alfa (que depois será retornado esse valor de inicio para alfa). alfa vai contabilizar quantos caracteres tem e vai adicionar ao endereço inicial de final, para que final esteja posicionado para ir decrementando. alfa recebe inicio novamente na posição inicial original.

Comment: sobre o final e printf que você falou, é só para saber o endereço que ficou, pois o printf está com o %p.. entendeu? Só para entender se ele calculou o endereço certo para posicionar no final e ficar no mesmo tamanho de alfa.

Comment: Então @arfneto, você quis dizer *final = NULL; Então, eu usei NULL pois a posição que ficou a variável final é para sinalizar o final de uma string. Pelo o que eu fiz, pode ser usado NULL também ou '\0'

Comment: acho que eu entendi o que você quis dizer de não inicializar a variável final. Então, eu fiz o seguinte: char *final = "xxxxxxxxxx"; e agora ele passa por todas as variáveis no loop. Contudo a atribuição de *final = *alfa; não vai. Engraçado que *alfa = *final; funciona!!

Comment: *alfa = *final; Está funcionando

void muda_letraa(char *alfa)
{
 char *inicio = alfa;
 char *final = "xxxxxxxxxx";
 
 while(*alfa)
  alfa++;

 final = final + (alfa - inicio);
 alfa = inicio;
 final--;
 printf("\n\n");
 while(*alfa)
 {
  printf("alfa => E: %p , V: %c      ============       final => E: %p , V: %c\n", alfa, *alfa, final, *final);
  //*final = *alfa;
  *alfa = *final;
  printf("alfa => E: %p , V: %c      ============       final => E: %p , V: %c\n", alfa, *alfa, final, *final);
  final--;
  alfa++;
 }
 
 final++;
}